# Tomcat 6 not working on windows 7

Tags: tomcat6

Tomcat 6 refuses to work in windows 7, it seems the problem is that it needs a 32bit jre, but i don't want to have a 64 and 32 bit installed. I want to get it to work with the 64bit jre and jdk. If anyone has encountered this problem and found a solution please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, the [Tomcat 6 download page](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) includes a 64-bit Windows version. Is there some reason you can't use that?

Answer (score 0):

I've found one page where the same problem is reported (tomcat 6 won't start as a service in a 64bit windows environment) and a solution is given. The page can be found [here](http://blog.ralscha.ch/?p=331) (it's in german language but google translate might make it readable).

In brief:

- Get tomcat6.exe and tomcat6w.exe from [here](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FTPSERVER-291?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel).
- overwrite the original files in your installation
- tomcat should now run.

(no guarantee, just translated something I found on the net)